# How to add a payment reference to RSForms!Pro?

Tags: rsform, joomla3.8, payment-gateway

Okay, so I have this Joomla website that I maintain for someone. It has the components RSForm! Pro and RSEvents!Pro installed. Every once in a while, we have an event, and the signup for it will be through a RSForm!Pro-form. This works fine. The only thing I cannot seem to find, is how to add a payment reference (for example, a fixed code and the name of the person filling in the form, so a form-field) to the payment. Payment is through Mollie.

There is one form that has it working, but I cannot find where it is configured. So what I do now is copy that one form, leave the fixed reference in place and change the rest of the form completely. But it bugs me that I cannot seem to find this information :/

Comment: When you say Mollie is the payment provider I'm thinking iDEAL. 
Is cciDEAL installed? You could find this at the Component menu.
Or perhaps the RSFom!Pro iDEAL plugin?
Documentation on the RSForms!pro ideal plugin here: https://www.rsjoomla.com/blog/view/415-rsformpro-ideal-plugin-launched.html

Comment: @WimdeRuijter theres RSEvents!Pro iDeal Payments installed. In this link though, i see some script that should help me;
$mollie = RSFormProMollie::getInstance();
 
    //then you can override parameters as in this example:
 
    $mollie->args['description'] = 'This is a new description.';

But I have no clue where to put it as it is in NONE of the other forms that do seem to work. But I will give it a go :)

Comment: So the iDEAL plugin in use is for RSEvents and not for RSForm?

Comment: Yep. 
But I solved this problem. Turns out there is some sort of script after posting that updates the payment reference (i assume in a similar manner as the plugin in the link you posted). It just needed two fields named exactly as in the form that has it working. So I added those fields and tweaked a little in the scripts-section that run on the Post-trigger. Anyway, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I had thought it was some sort of configuration on the form itself but it turns out to be configured somewhere I can't get to it haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this, so posting this answer for anyone who comes across the same problem in the future.

So, what happens is: After posting the form, a script is supposedly kicked off, similar to what happens with this plugin: https://www.rsjoomla.com/blog/view/415-rsformpro-ideal-plugin-launched.html

This is a script that is nowhere to be found in site configuration or anything, so I will need to go and ask the creator of the first working form where the script is exactly. Anyway, 'our' script takes two fields from a form and uses these for updating the payment reference. If one field is missing, obviously the script errors out and the payment reference is not updated.

The solution was adding both fields named exactly as in the working form and from there it works fine. My problem was caused by me not needing field nr 2, so I removed it from the form. Now, it is back as a hidden field, solely for payment reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by payment reference. The settings of most payment plugins in RSForm are set at the configuration level (RSForm Pro -> Configuration).

If you want to add an unsupported payment method, then the best way would be to download the authorize.net RSForm plugin and the modify it to adjust to your new payment method. Note that this is typically hard work, so it's better to buy this plugin if you can find it.

Comment: what i want, is when a payment is done through a form, it has sort of a code in the payment information on the bank-website. So that every payment that is done, can be easily categorized what it is for. Its sometimes over a 100 ppl paying and subscribing through these forms. It is difficult to keep track of payments (for financial reports) without some sort of a fixed reference with the payment. For example, all payments done through form X have 'FORMX'  in the payment info, all payments through form Y have 'FORMY' . I hope it is more clear now?